# Syncronization time jumps up to 8 days, then down again

Tags: litecoin, litecoin-qt

I'm relatively new to using the litecoin software.  I watched the local copy of the blockchain build all the way down to two days.  Suddenly, *it jumped back up* to 8 days, and then built all the way down to zero days and finished.  The time it took to go from 8 days down to zero was a lot faster than the normal build had been down to two days (about ten or fifteen minutes). Knowing that this latter part of the build would be *past all the checkpoints* (do I know that?), is there an issue here?

Answers to comment section:

Nick: No, the time was not altered, and the computer was never rebooted during the blockchain build.

Unfortunately, I deleted the blockchain, due to suspicion.  Now I wish I'd kept it for forensic analysis.

Comment: Did you change your computer's clock during this time?

Comment: @Jannes That is entirely irrelevant to the question, and a subjective opinion.